# Groovy string from gradle properties file behaving not as intended

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to publish a Java library to Bintray and encountered a weird behavior of strings that i get from the `gradle.properties` file.

Content of properties file:

```
testString = 'test'
```

My task for testing the string behavior:

```
task weirdString {
    println(testString)
    println('test')
    println(testString.class)
    println('test'.class)
    println(testString.equals('test'))
}
```

Running the task outputs:

```
'test'
test
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
false
```

I can't wrap my head around this. The difference between the first and the second output makes my deployment task crash. I guess this is some internal Groovy magic. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: hello, what about accepting an answer ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry, you probably answered so fast that i had to wait to accept it. It should be accepted now ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In properties files you do not need quotes to wrap strings. Just write

```
testString=test
```

Comment: Oh god, i am so stupid. Thank you very much, i have been at this for almost 2 hours :/

Comment: It's not true, that one does "not have to use" quotes, he **must not** use them without getting unintended results. Every entry in a Java properties file (this has nothing to do with Groovy or Gradle) is a string and everything behind the assigment sign will be added to the content of the string.